# Find the positive integer x such that $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{2003^2}$

Tags: number-theory

I tried other similar question's solution on here but it doesn't work with this problem. What theorem should I use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is $3$ a quadratic residue modulo $2003$?

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate of the post it was linked to, but do consider the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974682/solving-x2-equiv-3-pmod2003) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260996/how-can-i-solve-x2-equiv-19-pmod-59). Basically if a prime modulus (here it is $2003$) is of the form $4k+3$ then there is a recipe. Once you solve the problem for modulus $2003$, solve it for the modulus $2003^2$ by representing $x=x_0+2003n$ where $x_0$ is a solution for modulus $2003$.

Comment: (The "lifting" process to get a solution $\pmod{2003^2}$ from a solution $\pmod{2003}$ is called "[Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)" and the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769291/number-of-solutions-to-x2-equiv-b-mod-pn) has a [link](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m25f11/public_html/notes/class20.pdf) to an article explaining it in full generality.)

Comment: (The "recipe" for solving $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ is, by the way just checking if $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, and, if yes (i.e. if $a^\frac{p-1}{2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$), and if $p=4k+3$, the solution "just" comes out in the wash as $x\equiv \pm a^\frac{p+1}{4}\pmod{p}$.)